# Error Resources$NotFoundException for ImageView with vector drawable en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Acabo de recibir un informe de ANR en Googleplay Console de una app que un usuario se le ha manifestado usando mi app.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_circular_way.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02006a. If the resource you are trying to use is a vector resource, you may be referencing it in an unsupported way. See AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled() for more info.
...
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
```

Supongo que se refiere a que uso drawables en forma de vector.

En el gradle ya tengo definido el uso de

```
defaultConfig {
   ...
   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
   ...
}
```

Ese error proviene de Android 4.4 (KitKat)

Comment: Ya verificaste si en tu `build.gradle` cuentas con esto? `defaultConfig {
    generatedDensities = []
  }


  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }`

Comment: no lo tengo definido ahora pruebo

Comment: ya lo he solucionado ahora reporto la solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buscando la solución me he econtrado con esta respuesta de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615470/support-library-vectordrawable-resourcesnotfoundexception)

En el gradle definir si se usa 2.0 o superior

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    ...
}
```

Con el aporte de  @Miguel Osorio y complementando de [Android Support Library (III) – VectorDrawables](http://blog.asanchez-portfolio.es/asl-vectordrawables)

Si utilizamos una versión anterior

```
android {  
    defaultConfig {
        generatedDensities = []  
    }  

    aaptOptions {  
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
    }  

}
```

En el `OnCreate` de las actividades

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

En caso de utilizar recursos vectoriales en los laterales de un `TextView` usando la propiedad `android:drawableLeft` se debe englobar el vector en un `layer-list`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_12dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

y para usarlo:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_hackside_location_on_black"
```

Obtenido de la [respuesta SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800334/how-to-use-vector-drawables-with-view-besides-imageview-with-srccompat)

Comment: es lo mismo que yo te comente

Comment: me faltaba lo de appcompatdelegate en cada actividad para que acabará de funcionar pero ahora veo que tengo problemas con los drawables laterales drawableLeft...

Comment: @MiguelOsorio ya he actualizado la respuesta

Comment: @Webserveis hola Si lo solucionaste?

Comment: buenas @Elenasys si, ya lo solucioné bueno hasta que me vuelva a salir algun error a la carga de un recurso, pero en este proyecto si.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro del build.gradle debes tener:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
```

y al cargar estos graficos se deben crear primeramente mediante  `VectorDrawableCompat.create()` :

```
myImageView.setImageDrawable(VectorDrawableCompat.create(myImageView.getResorces(), R.drawable.ic_my_image, null));
```